# Gzip, Deflate Encoding in httpwebrequest vb.net

Tags: vb.net, encoding

so, i want to receive responce from server but i have error,

the problem in the encoding i dont know to do that in my case using vb.net :

```
Accept: */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

in the general case the code should be like this :

```
Dim postData As String = "{'text': 'je m appellle ihab'}"
    Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.reverso.net/orthographe/correcteur-francais/ServerInterface.asmx/GetLgDetect"), HttpWebRequest)
    postReq.Method = "POST"
    postReq.KeepAlive = True
    postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
    postReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    postReq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8")
    postReq.Referer = "http://www.reverso.net/orthographe/correcteur-francais/"
    postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
    postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
    postReq.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate
    Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postreqstream.Close()
    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
    postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
    logincookie = tempCookies
    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = thepage
```

i hope this is clear !

Comment: I am afraid that this is not clear :-( What error message do you have? And at which line in your code does the error occur?

Comment: Do you mean you want to receive a compressed stream? If that's the case, add this header: `[HttpWebRequest].Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8")` and set: `[HttpWebRequest].AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate`. Btw, this  i *want to receive responce from server but i have error* doesn't mean anything. You have to post the error you receive and/or the StatusCode of the error.

Comment: i add the full code, it not give me the response

Comment: Great! I ran your code and the website returned OK (200), i.e. Success, and the page contained `{"d":""}`. So what is wrong?

Comment: it should return a corrected text not {"d":""} , the site is a ortograohy corrector